# Is there a way to track when a Data Context hits the database?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using a Data Context object for a group of forms in a wpf application and I bind some controls to some child tables of a table. I want to track when exactly a Data Context accesses the database. What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Track where? In your application or on the database? The second one is easy: Profiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`DataContext.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property:

```
db.Log = Console.Out;
```

Where `db` is your `DataContext`. If you construct multiple instances of your `DataContext`, set the `Log` inside the `DataContext` constructor so that they are all logged appropriately.

You can use this technique to log to a file, memory, or the debug window, as shown [in this tutorial](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers). If you define a custom [`TextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) derivative, you can output the current `DateTime.Now` along with the relevant SQL statement whenever the database is accessed.

Your extension of `TextWriter` might look a bit like this:

```
class LoggingTextWriter : TextWriter 
{
    private const string LogFilePath = @"C:\your_log_file.txt";

    public override void Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count) 
    {
        Write(new String(buffer, index, count));
    }

    public override void Write(string value) 
    {
        File.AppendAllText(LogFilePath, DateTime.Now + value);
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.Default; }
    }
}
```

and

```
db.Log = new LoggingTextWriter();
```

Comment: Does the Log cache all SQL executed for the entire lifetime of the Data Context?

Comment: the `Log` is a `TextWriter`, so it doesn't *cache* - it *streams* the SQL queries at the point in time when they are sent to the database (during or after `db.SubmitChanges`).